# Automatically run AWS Glue job when the job is created or updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue, aws-cdk

I have [AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc) jobs setup to upload test data to our database. Uploading takes place only 1 time and no additional runs are required unless additions or changes are required on the test data. However, we have multiple environments where the upload needs to happen. One way is to deploy the jobs using [CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/) and manually run the jobs in each environment. Looking for pointers to automatically trigger a run when the jobs is either updated or created.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CustomResource to invoke it via command line or the Glue SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to remember that CDK is not a deployment solution - it is an infrastructure as code solution. CDK does not actually do any deployment - the `cdk deploy` command is just a shortcut for sending the template to CloudFormation.

CDK is just a way to lay code over top the creation of the CloudFormation templates and give developers far more options. All it really does is generate a CloudFormation Template - everything else is window dressing.

As such, anything that has to happen *after* the CloudFormation template is synthed and deployed is not possible for CDK to interact with.  You need to make a custom resource that can watch for Stack Updates and when the stack is done deploying, trigger whatever else you want.

Alternatively, this is a perfect use of CodePipeline - run your cdk in the the pipeline (either with a Synth and CodeDeploy stages or a single codeBuild that just runs cdk deploy) and then in a stage after it have a lambda that triggers your jobs.